# How to restrict access to a specific G Suite user after suspend

Tags: g-suite

I was asked to cancel a G Suite suspended account, so that I can provide restricted access to another user that requires access. The former owner of this account gave his approval for that.

I would like to reactivate this account but with only restricted access:

- no way to remove mails
- prevent new mails to be received or answered, eventually prevent mails to be forwarded except for a restricted list of account into the organization
- only allow G Mail and Drive use

If I remember well I think that on previous G Suite versions this could be achieved by creating a new organization (and not a domain) and to assign some users to that restricted profile.

Any idea?

Regards,

NB: We are currently running on G Suite basic plan.

Comment: Currently I found interesting things in "Apps --> G Suite --> Settings for Gmail --> 
Advanced settings", after that I can choose one Organizational Unit and tweak General Settings for one unit like "Restricted User".

Also, adding a setting in Default routing may be helpful.

Comment: Confirmed that using Default routing and adding a new entry with matching rule to a restricted group and using action Reject message works.